# Max memory for hhvm instance on vServer

Tags: php, memory, nginx, settings, hhvm

Im tried hhvm on my vServer and have problems with the memory used. The performance is great, but the used memory consumption is horrible. I have a vServer with min 4GB and max 8GB memory and hhvm uses after 1 day about 2.4GB of the available memory - but still rising.

Is there a option in server.ini to set the max memory which should be used for the hhvm process?

I'm currently running Typo3 and Prestashop inside hhvm

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
}
```

and server.ini

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific

;hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.file_socket = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
```

Answer (score 0):

The [HHVM wiki has a fairly complete list of options](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/INI-Settings). I'm not aware of any one that controls maximum memory usage.

But what is the runtime supposed to do when it hits that maximum, anyways? I'm not sure it would be a useful option.

If you're seeing monotonically increasing memory usage over time, you should [file a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) so we can help you get a heap profile and figure out what is causing the memory increase. That shouldn't be happening. There are a few known bugs that we might be able to help you work around -- any usage of `create_function` is known to leak right now, for example -- or maybe you've found some new leak that we can fix.